# Open a connection to MySQL with ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server with ASP.net (c#) without success.

- Framework .NET 4.5
- MySQL5.5
- Hosting provider: 1&1

The funny thing is that I can connect without problems using PHP. This is the code that i use in ASP NET:

```
MySqlCommand com;
object obj;
string strcon = "Server=hostname;Database=dbname;Uid=myid;Pwd=mypass;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon);
con.Open();
```

On the last line I get this error:

> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]

After a lot of searching on the web I tried:

- To change my trust level -> **Not possible due the provider policy**
- Change version of the Framework -> **Both 4.0 and 3.5 does not works**

Then I start to do funny things, like creating a PHP class to connect to the DB and then send the result to the ASP.NET classes, but is not very confortable...
Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the version of the Connector/NET you are using?

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago, and there is not much to be done since it is a security issue. In a different hosting provider I was able to run ASP.NET + MySQL+EF in medium trust environment.I remember that I tried several versions to make it work. For me, the working version was 6.4.4.0. My hosting provider has a custom trust level, it was medium trust in overall, but it would allow connections from the Connector/NET. Basically there is not much you can do, since you can not alter security settings.

Comment: From the error message, it is clearly show that you need to run in full trust permission. If your hosting provider doesnt support full trust, then it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing`pwd=mypass` to`password=mypass` you may refer this [link](http://www.sqlstrings.com/MySQL-connection-strings.htm) below for brief content. hope this works.